# How to get value from expression in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, get

I have the following string expression:

```
str="1+2+3+4"
```

Now from this string I want the value of number (10). How can I get this value from this expression?

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, you'd have to parse all the numbers, something like this

```
Dim str As String= "1+2+3+4"
Dim numbers() As String = str.Split('+')
Dim result As Integer = 0
For Each number As String In numbers
    result += Integer.Parse(number)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, but if the expression has multiple operators, eg 1 + 2 * 3/4 ^ 5.Then how

Comment: @SonLe you'd need to Split on each character, and save which operation was entered as separator.

Comment: I use  "NCalc" but had problems with the operator "^". Dim e As Expression = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5")
Msgbox(17 = e.Evaluate())

Comment: This is not a trivial problem and the question is very broad. There are examples to be found in the internet on using expression trees https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After the evening of searching I have solved the problem. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41466b93-56cb-4dd0-8a16-d53aec3c4a2f/evaluating-a-string-expression-in-vbnet?forum=vblanguage

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that uses `Linq`. This solution excludes nothing it can not parse...

```
 YOURSTRING.Split("+").ToList.Where(Function(sr) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sr) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(sr, New Integer)).Sum(Function(s As String) Integer.Parse(s))
```

**Example Output**

1. 1+2+3+4 = **10**
2. 1+2+3+4++12+1 = **23** (Notice the typo (**4++12**), it still works even it there's a mistake)